# Serial transmit in named pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to transfer data sequentially to a named pipe (FIFO). To do this, I call sequential commands in the background:

```
(echo "text1" > pipe &); (echo "text2" > pipe &); (echo "text3" > pipe &);
```

In the same process, I call the following command:

```
cat pipe
```

And I expect to get the following output:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

But I am getting random order in the output:

```
text2
text1
text3
```

Is it possible to get the same order at the output as at the input?

Comment: The ordering of parallel processes in the background is not deterministic as they are all scheduled independently. What do you actually need to achieve?

Comment: I want to use a named pipe as a buffer: first, information is written there in stages, and then output in the same order. But the write command blocks the terminal until the data is read in the named pipe. Because of this, need to use background process.

Comment: If you want the three background jobs to run in order, try `{ task1; task2; task3; } &` Be careful not to omit any spaces or semi-colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of parallel processes in the background is not deterministic as they are all scheduled independently.

If you want the three background jobs to run in order, in the background, try:

```
{ task1; task2; task3; } &
```

Be careful not to omit any spaces or semi-colons.